# Creating a User Account For Every Hospital Instance Created - Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'll like that everytime an hospital is created, A corresponding User account is created likewise, allowing the newly created account to login....

models.py

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing individual Hospitals
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, db_index=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    hospital_name = models.CharField(help_text="full name of hospital", max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    hospital_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='hospital_logo',)
    hospital_address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    hospital_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    hospital_website = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    hospital_rc_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
class HospitalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Forms for Hospital creation
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Hospital
        fields = ('hospital_name', 'hospital_address', 'hospital_email', 'hospital_website', 'hospital_rc_number','hospital_logo')

        widgets = {

            'hospital_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_website': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_rc_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def save(self):
        instance = super(HospitalForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.hospital_name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class HospitalCreate(CreateView):
    model = Hospital
    form_class = HospitalForm
    template_name = 'hospital/hospital_add.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'hospital_id'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('hospital_list')
    user_form = UserForm
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the best way to go about this, But it seems to be doing what i want. I'm yet to fully check if other issues will pop-up.
I created more fields in the hospital model that corresponded to the fields in the User class, and i was able to use the `object.create_user` method to create instances of the hospital model in the User class.

models.py

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing individual Hospitals
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, db_index=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    admin_username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=15)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.IntegerField()
    hospital_name = models.CharField(help_text="full name of hospital", max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    hospital_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='hospital_logo',)
    hospital_address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    hospital_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    hospital_website = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    hospital_rc_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
class HospitalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Forms for Hospital creation
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Hospital
        fields = ('hospital_name', 'hospital_address', 'hospital_email', 'hospital_website', 'hospital_rc_number',
                  'first_name','last_name','hospital_logo','admin_username','password','password2')

        widgets = {

            'admin_username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_website': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hospital_rc_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def save(self):
        instance = super(HospitalForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.hospital_name)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

And Views.py

```
class HospitalCreate(CreateView):
    model = Hospital
    form_class = HospitalForm
    template_name = 'hospital/hospital_add.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'hospital_id'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('hospital_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.instance.admin_username
        password = form.instance.password
        email = form.instance.hospital_email
        first_name = form.instance.first_name
        last_name = form.instance.last_name

        user_profile = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email,first_name=first_name,
                                                last_name=last_name, is_staff='0', is_active='1')

        user_profile.save()

        form.instance.user = int(user_profile.id)

        return super(HospitalCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add user creation to your views [`form_valid` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid)

```
class HospitalCreate(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()

        # create user here

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Did this help you? Could you get it working? If so, I would appreciate an upvote (or if you marked the answer as accepted).